# application.cfc in subdir not getting session variables from application.cfm in the parent directory

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I have an application.cfc in folder /wwwRoot/beta/. They have an application.cfm in the root which sets bunch of session variables. When I hit one of the pages in the beta folder to dump all the session vars, I don't see the ones that were defined in the application.cfm.

I modified my application.cfc to get rid of all the code within 'onSessionStart'. That didn't help. I created a new application.cfm with a few application varibales I needed. That didn't help either.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
   <cffunction name="onSessionStart" returnType="void" output="false" hint="Fires ONLY ONCE when session first created and not when session renewed/restarted.">
    <cfscript>
        session.startTime = Now();

    </cfscript>
    <cfreturn>
</cffunction>
```

I guess I will need to some how copy existing session vars.

I created a simple test page on the above folder.

```
<cfset session.mynum= 1111>
 <a href="beta/index.cfm">clicky</a>
```

When I click on the link, the session dump does not include myNum. Something in application.cfc is screwing things around.

Comment: This question can't be answered unless you post the source to the Application.cfc in the /wwwRoot/beta/ folder, as well as the Application.cfm in the /wwwRoot/ parent. There are a number of things that it could be, and without seeing the code, we can't move further with answers.

Comment: On a side note, if i delete application.cfc, i can see all the session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! In the application.cfc I have the following at the top:

```
 <cfscript>
   this.name = "myApp";
 </cfscipt>
```

the name of the application must be as same as the one that is being used in the  tag in application.cfm. Once the name was changed, I was able to get the session vars.

thanks

Comment: That isn't a solution.  If you hit the page in the subfolder first the session variables wont exist and you will get an error unless you have error handlers or you check for the variable's existence first.

Answer (score 0):

Application.cfc will not be affected by an Application.cfm in the parent folder.  You should replace the Application.cfm with an Application.cfc and then in your child folder you should extend the parent Application.cfc.  This is the way the Application framework in ColdFusion functions.

That said, if you cannot replace the Application.cfm with an Application.cfc then you could break out the session variable definition into a separate file and then cfinclude it into the Application.cfm and repeat that inclusion in the Application.cfc in the child folder.  However, you may have other things in your Application.cfm that will also not be included in the Application.cfc in the child folder so this isn't really a great solution.  The best solution is to get rid of the Application.cfm altogether, replace it with a proper Application.cfc in the root and then extend that from any child folders as necessary.

Comment: Converting application.cfm to application.cfc is not an option.

Comment: OK, well I gave you another option though it's not a great one.  You are trying to mesh together two solutions that aren't designed or intended to work together in that way.  You could also replace the Application.cfc with another Application.cfm and cfinclude the parent Application.cfm